# SVG circles pulse synchronous doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to position one circle svg for each click I do on the object window.

My function works fine but what can I do to make circles pulse synchronous?

```
window.addEventListener("click",
    function(event){
        var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");

        circleDiv.innerHTML = "<svg><circle cx='80' cy='80' r='20' stroke='black' fill='white' fill-opacity='0.0' /></svg>";
        circleDiv.style.position = "absolute";
        circleDiv.style.left = event.x+'px';
        circleDiv.style.top  = event.y+'px';

        var direction = 5;
        var radius = 20;

        window.setInterval(function()
        {
            radius = radius + direction;
            if(radius<10) direction = 5;
            if(radius>50) direction = -5;
            circleDiv.firstChild.firstChild.setAttribute("r",radius);
        },500);

        myBody.appendChild(circleDiv);

    }
);
```

Comment: Please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how to ask questions on SO. Questions like: Give me the solutions to XY are not likely to be answered. What have you done so far? What do you mean by `make circles pulse synchronous`. Futhermore, an overuse of punctuation marks does not make anyone to answer more quickly

Comment: Ok sorry. I am going to modify as soon as possible my question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'synchronus' you talk about pusle together you must split your function as is :

```
var direction = 1;
var radius = 20;


window.addEventListener("click",
    function(event){
        var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");

        circleDiv.innerHTML = "<svg><circle cx='80' cy='80' r='" + radius + "' stroke='black' fill='white' fill-opacity='0.0' /></svg>";
        circleDiv.style.position = "absolute";
        circleDiv.style.left = event.x+'px';
        circleDiv.style.top  = event.y+'px';    

        myBody.appendChild(circleDiv);

    }
);


window.setInterval(function()
{
    var circles = document.getElementsByTagName('circle');
    radius = radius + direction;
    if(radius<10) direction = 1;
    if(radius>50) direction = -1;

    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circle = circles[i];
        circle.setAttribute("r",radius);
    }
 },20);
```

[Here the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qkuk89w/7/)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Yes it helps :) this is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you add the circles capture them in an array `circles` and have just one timer to update their sizes. Note I added putting your handlers in the jquery document ready function. This is good practise. Try this:

```
var circles = [];
var radius = 20;
var direction = 5;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");

    circleDiv.innerHTML = "<svg><circle cx='80' cy='80' r='20' stroke='black' fill='white' fill-opacity='0.0' /></svg>";
    circleDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    circleDiv.style.left = event.x + 'px';
    circleDiv.style.top  = event.y + 'px';

    circles.push(circleDiv);

    myBody.appendChild(circleDiv);

    });

  window.setInterval(function() {
    radius = radius + direction;
    if(radius<10) direction = 5;
    if(radius>50) direction = -5;
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
      circles[i].firstChild.firstChild.setAttribute("r",radius);
    }
   } ,500);


});
```

You might want to make sure the SVG you create is using the `radius` value to set the starting size.